# Deploying WebService in Mule not working

Tags: web-services, mule, javabeans

I am trying to deploy a webservice in Mule but I am having some errors.
I tried many methods from adding it as a java class (simple service), to using it as a java beans.
Kindly find below the code for my mule flow, and the error message I got.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.
Flow

```
<spring:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">
        <spring:bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <spring:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <spring:property name="url"
                value="jdbc:postgresql://***********" />
            <spring:property name="username" value="******" />
            <spring:property name="password" value="*****" />
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="userDao" class="com.logixy.platform.dao.UserJdbcTemplate">
            <spring:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="organizationDao"
            class="com.logixy.platform.dao.OrganizationJdbcTemplate">
            <spring:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="organizationUnitDao"
            class="com.logixy.platform.dao.OrganizationUnitJdbcTemplate">
            <spring:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="applicationDao"
            class="com.logixy.platform.dao.ApplicationJdbcTemplate">
            <spring:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="userSettingsDao"
            class="com.logixy.platform.dao.UserSettingsJdbcTemplate">
            <spring:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="userRoleDao"
            class="com.logixy.platform.dao.UserRoleJdbcTemplate">
            <spring:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="administrationWS"
            class="com.logixy.platform.ws.AdministrationServiceImpl">
            <spring:property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />
            <spring:property name="organizationDao" ref="organizationDao" />
            <spring:property name="organizationUnitDao" ref="organizationUnitDao" />
            <spring:property name="applicationDao" ref="applicationDao" />
            <spring:property name="userSettingsDao" ref="userSettingsDao" />
            <spring:property name="userRoleDao" ref="userRoleDao" />
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>
    <flow name="logixy-core-ws-flow" doc:name="logixy-core-ws-flow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <cxf:simple-service serviceClass="com.logixy.platform.ws.AdministrationService"
            doc:name="SOAP" />
        <component doc:name="Java">
            <spring-object bean="administrationWS"/>
        </component>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Error Message

```
INFO  2014-07-24 10:53:28,235 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising RegistryBroker
INFO  2014-07-24 10:53:28,405 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleApplicationContext: Refreshing org.mule.config.spring.MuleApplicationContext@3e9504f2: startup date [Thu Jul 24 10:53:28 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  2014-07-24 10:53:30,729 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising model: _muleSystemModel
INFO  2014-07-24 10:53:30,781 [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource: Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver
WARN  2014-07-24 10:53:30,861 [main] org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor: Invalid JavaBean property 'port' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.mule.endpoint.URIBuilder.setPort(java.lang.String)]: [public void org.mule.endpoint.URIBuilder.setPort(int)]
INFO  2014-07-24 10:53:30,958 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising connector: connector.http.mule.default
INFO  2014-07-24 10:53:31,030 [main] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Initialising flow: logixy-core-ws-flow
INFO  2014-07-24 10:53:31,031 [main] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: Initialising exception listener: org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy@3f3611ac
INFO  2014-07-24 10:53:31,043 [main] org.mule.processor.SedaStageLifecycleManager: Initialising service: logixy-core-ws-flow.stage1
INFO  2014-07-24 10:53:31,214 [main] org.mule.module.cxf.config.WebServiceFactoryBean: Built CXF Inbound MessageProcessor for service class com.logixy.platform.ws.AdministrationService
WARN  2014-07-24 10:53:31,219 [main] org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean: A JAX-WS Annotation was found on com.logixy.platform.ws.AdministrationService while using the Simple frontend.  For better results, use the JAX-WS frontend.
WARN  2014-07-24 10:53:31,224 [main] org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean: A JAX-WS Annotation was found on com.logixy.platform.ws.AdministrationService while using the Simple frontend.  For better results, use the JAX-WS frontend.
INFO  2014-07-24 10:53:31,444 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing model: _muleSystemModel
ERROR 2014-07-24 10:53:31,445 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo$1.compare(BeanTypeInfo.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo$1.compare(BeanTypeInfo.java:306)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:329)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:203)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo.initializeProperties(BeanTypeInfo.java:305)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo.<init>(BeanTypeInfo.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.java5.AnnotatedTypeInfo.<init>(AnnotatedTypeInfo.java:41)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.java5.AnnotatedTypeInfo.<init>(AnnotatedTypeInfo.java:36)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.java5.Java5TypeCreator.createDefaultType(Java5TypeCreator.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.XMLTypeCreator.createDefaultType(XMLTypeCreator.java:398)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.createTypeForClass(AbstractTypeCreator.java:136)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.createType(AbstractTypeCreator.java:421)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.java5.Java5TypeCreator.getOrCreateParameterizedType(Java5TypeCreator.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.java5.Java5TypeCreator.getOrCreateMapValueType(Java5TypeCreator.java:151)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.getOrCreateMapValueType(AbstractTypeCreator.java:289)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.XMLTypeCreator.getOrCreateMapValueType(XMLTypeCreator.java:584)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.createMapType(AbstractTypeCreator.java:303)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.createTypeForClass(AbstractTypeCreator.java:119)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.createType(AbstractTypeCreator.java:396)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo.getType(BeanTypeInfo.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanType.getDependencies(BeanType.java:532)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.addDependencies(AegisDatabinding.java:398)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.addDependencies(AegisDatabinding.java:403)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.addDependencies(AegisDatabinding.java:403)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.initializeMessage(AegisDatabinding.java:374)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.initializeOperation(AegisDatabinding.java:280)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.initialize(AegisDatabinding.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:445)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:508)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:242)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.build(AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.java:210)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.build(AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.java:66)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.initialise(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:96)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:83)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialiseIfInitialisable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:318)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doInitialise(AbstractPipeline.java:212)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:113)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:107)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:81)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialise(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:119)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:57)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:207)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:47)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:58)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:91)
INFO  2014-07-24 10:53:31,448 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'logixy-core-ws' never started, nothing to dispose of
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: NullPointerException: 
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:219)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:47)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:58)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:91)
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'logixy-core-ws-flow': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: null (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:207)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'logixy-core-ws-flow': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: null (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:57)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Error creating bean with name 'logixy-core-ws-flow': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: null
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:117)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:119)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logixy-core-ws-flow': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: null
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.initialise(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:100)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:83)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialiseIfInitialisable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:318)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doInitialise(AbstractPipeline.java:212)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:113)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:107)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:81)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialise(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo$1.compare(BeanTypeInfo.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo$1.compare(BeanTypeInfo.java:306)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:329)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:203)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo.initializeProperties(BeanTypeInfo.java:305)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo.<init>(BeanTypeInfo.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.java5.AnnotatedTypeInfo.<init>(AnnotatedTypeInfo.java:41)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.java5.AnnotatedTypeInfo.<init>(AnnotatedTypeInfo.java:36)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.java5.Java5TypeCreator.createDefaultType(Java5TypeCreator.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.XMLTypeCreator.createDefaultType(XMLTypeCreator.java:398)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.createTypeForClass(AbstractTypeCreator.java:136)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.createType(AbstractTypeCreator.java:421)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.java5.Java5TypeCreator.getOrCreateParameterizedType(Java5TypeCreator.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.java5.Java5TypeCreator.getOrCreateMapValueType(Java5TypeCreator.java:151)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.getOrCreateMapValueType(AbstractTypeCreator.java:289)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.XMLTypeCreator.getOrCreateMapValueType(XMLTypeCreator.java:584)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.createMapType(AbstractTypeCreator.java:303)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.createTypeForClass(AbstractTypeCreator.java:119)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.AbstractTypeCreator.createType(AbstractTypeCreator.java:396)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo.getType(BeanTypeInfo.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanType.getDependencies(BeanType.java:532)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.addDependencies(AegisDatabinding.java:398)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.addDependencies(AegisDatabinding.java:403)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.addDependencies(AegisDatabinding.java:403)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.initializeMessage(AegisDatabinding.java:374)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.initializeOperation(AegisDatabinding.java:280)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding.initialize(AegisDatabinding.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:445)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:508)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:242)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.build(AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.java:210)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.build(AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.java:66)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.initialise(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:96)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the `cxf:simple-service` element is placed in the `inbound-endpoint`.

So please try with:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
    host="localhost" port="8081" />
  <cxf:simple-service serviceClass="com.logixy.platform.ws.AdministrationService" />
</http:inbound-endpoint>
<component>
  <spring-object bean="administrationWS" />
</component>
```